# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'NewFilmLikes' in Python

Tags: python, sqlite, valueerror

I am trying to get a value from an SQLite3 database and put that into a variable called FilmLikes, I then want to add one to it and I store that in the variable NewFilmLikes. I then try to change the value of this box in my database to the 'NewFilmLikes', however I always get this problem:

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'NewFilmLikes'

Here is the code showing that:

```
FilmLikes=i[2]
NewFilmLikes=(int(FilmLikes))+1
filmUpdate=("UPDATE HORRORALL SET likes = ? WHERE number = 1"(NewFilmLikes))
c.execute(filmUpdate)
conn.commit()
```

Here is the code for i:

```
for i in find_film:
                            print('')
                            print('Number',(i[0]))
                            print(i[1])
                        filmChoice=int(input('Please choose which number you would like to like: '))
                        if filmChoice==1:
                            find_film=c.execute("SELECT * FROM HORRORALL")
                            for i in find_film:
                                if i[0]==filmChoice:
##                                    FilmLikes=i[2]
                                    try:
                                        x=(int(i[2]))+1
                                    except:
                                        pass
##                                        FilmLikes=i[2]
##                                    NewFilmLikes=(int(str(FilmLikes)))+1
                                    filmUpdate=("UPDATE HORRORALL SET likes = ? WHERE number = 1"(x))
                                    c.execute(filmUpdate)
                                    conn.commit()
```

Comment: Show the code for `i`.

Comment: I have added it into the main post @CL

Comment: The two code excerpts are inconsistent with each other. Why are you showing commented-out code? Ensure that the indentation is correct and consistent.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing much more about your setup, it's hard to answer this properly.
 Mind you, the specific error you refer to (`ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'NewFilmLikes'`) often occurs when you get a decimal rather than an integer.

Here's a sort of general answer.

1. It's good practice not to use `SELECT *` because it hides what you are trying to retrieve. Specify, e.g `SELECT film_id, file_name, no_of_likes FROM horrorall` as this way you can see what you are retrieving and the positions.
2. You're retrieving the entire list of films with `find_film` and then looping through to find which one. SQL has a find function, it's called `WHERE` and you are using it in the `film_update` section. If you have the ID or Name inputted by the user, you can then call only the record you need. E.g. `"SELECT film_id, file_name, no_of_likes FROM horrorall WHERE film_id = ?" (filmChoice,)`
3. Note that parameterised queries use a tuple, even if there is only one parameter - hence it is (filmChoice,) with a comma (and for `filmUpdate` you would need `(x,)`)
4. `filmUpdate` will only ever update the first film. I assume that because your `if ...` loop continues through all the possible options? You can shortly this by putting another `?` in there for your `WHERE` e.g. `filmUpdate=("UPDATE HORRORALL SET likes = ? WHERE number = ?"(x,i[0]))`
5. How does the user know what film to select? You aren't retrieving the list until they give you a number!

Putting all of this together, here is an example. Note this is far from the ideal way of doing it, I don't want to throw too many ideas at you in one go!

```
# Get the whole list of films to show to the user
find_film = c.execute("SELECT film_id, film_name FROM HORRORALL")
# Present the list for selection
for films in find_film:
    print(str(films[0]) + '. ' + films[1])
# Get the users input as an integer
filmChoice = int(input('Please choose which number you would like to like: '))
# Fetch the number of likes of the selected film
film_likes = c.execute('SELECT likes FROM HORRORALL WHERE film_id = ?' (filmChoice,))
# Send the update back to the database
c.execute("UPDATE HORRORALL SET likes = ? WHERE film_id = ?"(int(film_likes[0]) + 1, filmChoice)
conn.commit()
```